# Transition behaviour when inheriting

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, chromium, brave

Today i have found interesting behaviour of transition when nested elements use inherit keyword. Without inherit transition on all nested elements is triggered immediately. Whereas when inheriting transition is triggered in cascade. (As mentioned in comments, this behaviour is specific to chromium)

Without inherit

```js
const change = document.getElementById("change");
let toggler = true;
change.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggler = !toggler;
    document.documentElement.style
    .setProperty('--color', toggler ? "black" : "red");
})
```

```css
::root{
  --color: "black";
}

* {
  transition: color 1s;
  color: var(--color);
}

.test {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Text level1
  <div>
    Text level2
    <div>
      Text level3
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="change">
    ChangeColor
  </button>
</div>
```

With inherit

```js
const change = document.getElementById("change");
let toggler = true;
change.addEventListener("click", () => {
toggler = !toggler;
    document.documentElement.style
    .setProperty('--color', toggler ? "black" : "red");
    
})
```

```css
::root{
  --color: "black";
}

* {
  transition: color 1s;
  color: var(--color);
}

.test {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  Text level1
  <div class="test">
    Text level2
    <div class="test">
      Text level3
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="change">
    ChangeColor
  </button>
</div>
```

Is there a way how to change colors immediately even when using inherit?

Comment: this is only specific to Chrome, Firefox will behave the same in both cases

Comment: Oh, good point. Thanks

Comment: In 2023, this still is the case in Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox. Any workaround other than adding `color 0s` to the transition?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but it does work if you need a workaround and know all inheritance sources.

First, in the `*` rule, disable the transition for the `color` property:

```css
* {
  transition: all 1s, color 0s;
}
```

Then, go to the "source" of the color changes and add

```
.some-source-of-color {
   transition: color 1s;
}
```

Here it is a similar example to the question's.

```js
const change = document.getElementById("change");
let toggler = true;
change.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("root").classList.toggle("test");
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
  transition: color 1s;
}
* {
  transition: all 1s, color 0s;
}
/*
The problem would be present if we didn't have `, color 0s` above
*/
```

```html
<div id="root">
  Text level1
  <div>
    Text level2
    <div>
      Text level3
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="change">
    ChangeColor
  </button>
</div>
```